# Only one data is inserted in mongoose mlab database

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

In my UserSchema which is in my **InfoUser.js** this is how i construct my code

**InfoUser.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

//User Schema
//authToken and isAuthenticated is for UserSchema of email-verification
var UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
username:{
    type: String,
    index:true,
    unique:true
},
influenceid:{
    type:String
},
question:{
    type:String
},
amount:{
    type:Number
},
ifAnswer:{
    type:String
},
TimeAnswer:{
    type:Date
    // default:Date.now
},
Done:{
    type:Boolean
}
},{timestamps:{createdAt:'created_at'}});


//accesible variable from the outside
var InfoUser = module.exports = mongoose.model('infousers', UserSchema);

//create the user
module.exports.createUser= function(newUser, callback){
    newUser.save(callback);
}
```

And on my server.js i insert the data like this

**server.js**

```
 socket.on('dollar quest', function(dolquest,dolamnt,uid,stud,stat){
    var info = new InfoUser({
        username: stud,
        amount:parseInt(dolamnt),
        question: dolquest,
        influenceid:uid
    });

    InfoUser.createUser(info,function(err,user){
        if(err)throw err;
        console.log(user);
    });
    io.emit('tech notif',uid,stud,stat);
});
});
```

Now my code of inserting data is fine but the problem is that whenever I try to perform another transaction it does not insert anymore. Someone help me, please . Why is it not inserting more data on mlab.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
info.save(function(err, result) 
          {
            response.json({code :0 , result});
          });
```

Comment: any console problems?

Comment: It is always recommended that you provide a description of your answer and why you think it is correct.  Code-only answers tend to be frowned upon.